# Relationship between Origin Access Identities (OAIs) and CloudFront Signed URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I've been following guides on CloudFront and S3 and I feel like I am still missing a core piece of information in the relationship between Origin Access Identities (OAIs) and CloudFront Signed URLs.

**What I want**: a private CDN to host audio snippets (of a few seconds in length) and low-resolution images. I only want these files to be accessible when requested from a specific domain (i.e. the domain the web app will live on) and maybe a testing server, so that my web app can get the files but anyone else just can't access them without going through the web app.

**What I'm confused about**: I'm fuzzy on the relationship (if there is any) between CloudFront Origin Access Identities (OAIs) and Signed CloudFront URLs.

I have currently created a private S3 bucket, an OAI for my CloudFront distribution, and have generated a signed URL to an image through CloudFront. But I don't see how these things are related and how they prevent someone else from accessing CDN files (e.g. if they were able to inspect an element and get the signed URL).

Is the whole point to make sure the signed URLs expire quickly? And if so, how does the OAI play a role in it? Is this something set in CORS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An origin access identity is an entity inside CloudFront that 
can be authorized by bucket policy to access objects in a bucket.  When CloudFront uses an origin access identity to access content in a bucket, CloudFront uses the OAI's credentials to generate a signed request that it sends to the bucket to fetch the content.  This signature is not accessible to the viewer.

The meaning of the word "origin" as used here should not be confused with the word "origin" as used in other contexts, such as CORS, where "origin" refers to the site that is allowed to access the content.

**The origin access identity has nothing to do with access being restricted to requests containing a specific `Origin` or `Referer` header.**

Once a signed URL is validated by CloudFront as matching a CloudFront signing key associated with your AWS account (or another account that you designate as a trusted signer) the object is fetched from the bucket, using whatever permissions the origin access identity has been granted at the bucket.

> Is the whole point to make sure the signed url's expire quickly?

Essentially, yes.

Authentication and Authorization of requests by trying to restrict access based on the site where the link was found is *not* a viable security measure.  It prevents hot-linking from other sites, but does nothing to protect against anyone who can forge request headers.  Defeating a measure like that is trivial.

Signed URLs, by contrast, are extremely tamper resistant to the point of computational infeasibility.

A signed URL is not only valid only until it expires, but can optionally also restrict access to a person having the same IP address that's included in the policy document, if you use a [custom policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html).  Once signed, any change to the URL, including the policy statement, makes the entire URL unusable.

The OAI is only indirectly connected with CloudFront signed URLs -- they can be used individually, or together -- but without an OAI, CloudFront has no way to prove that it is authorized to request objects from your bucket, so the bucket would need to be public, which would defeat much of the purpose of signed URLs on CloudFront.

Comment: Got it. So trying to restrict access so only my site can access cdn files isn't a good approach? I'm better off just creating url's with reasonable expire times or url's with custom policies that IP restricts to only allow access to my site (domain)?

Comment: Trying to restrict so that your site, magically, by virtue of the fact that the web browser *claims* it is a request from your site is a primitive form of protecting content.   Yes URLs with expiration is better.  A signed URL restricted to the *user's* IP can also help if you have a concern of users "sharing" the URLs.  Note the IP is the user's IP -- not your site's IP.  The idea, generally, is to generate the signed URLs as the page is rendered.  Let me know of this answer needs more detail or clarification.

Comment: I see, thank you. My concern was less with users sharing URL's and more with hotlinking of material on the webapp (the audio files and images). Bandwidth usage aside, those files should not be accessed outside the webapp for anyone else

Comment: If you aren't concerned about security of the content (e.g. medical images, proprietary documents, sensitive data), but instead just want to prevent hotlinking, then it's possible to not use signed URLs and to instead just block on the `Referer` header by using AWS [Web Application Firewall](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) with CloudFront.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new CNAME entry that points to your CloudFront domain. This entry should match that entered in the ‘Alternate Domain Names’ from within the CloudFront console.

[image]

By default CloudFront generate Domain name automatically (eg d3i29vunzqzxrt.cloudfront.net) but you can define your alternative domain name.

Also you can secure Cloudfront
[Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Comment: Ok. Wouldn't a CDN only change the url? How would that ensure that on one else other than my specified domain can access the items on the CDN?

Comment: You can optionally secure the content in your Amazon S3 bucket so users can access it through CloudFront but cannot access it directly by using Amazon S3 URLs. This prevents anyone from bypassing CloudFront and using the Amazon S3 URL to get content that you want to restrict access to. This step isn't required to use signed URLs
--AWS