# 403 Forbidden when visiting my website-url via CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am using CloudFront in combination with a S3-bucket.

When I access my CloudFront-domain (d4...cloudfront.net) directly, everything works fine and I can see my website + SSL-certificate.

But when I access my website-url, I get an 403 Forbidden-message (An Error Occurred While Attempting to Retrieve a Custom Error Document).

This is the error I get:
[image]

This is the response-header:
[image]

What I tried so far:

- When I created the CloudFront-distribution, I selected "Origin Access Identity: Create a new Identity" and "Update Bucket Policy"
- I added a Custom Error Page, which returns StatusCode 200 and /index.html as the respone page

My S3 bucket is not public, because I only want my CloudFront to access the S3-Bucket with this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin 
                Access Identity ..."
           },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.../*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* error, headers and body.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I just added the error-message and the header

Comment: The error is from S3.  Your error message is HTML, not XML, which means you are using the web site endpoint of the bucket, not the REST endpoint.  An Origin Access Identity only works with REST endpoints.

Comment: does it mean I have to change the origin domain name of my CloudFront-configuration? Where can I find the REST-endpoint of my S3-bucket ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change it. Create a new origin and start typing the bucket name, and you should be able to then select the bucket from the drop-down list.  This is the REST endpoint.  Then change the Cache Behaviors to use the new origin.

Comment: I did that when I initialized my CloudFront. My Endpoint has this structure: www.mywebsiteurl.com.s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: Oh... You know what?  I overlooked the fact that your error message indicates you aren't actually using CloudFront at all.  Your web site hostname, in DNS, must still be pointing at the bucket.

Comment: ok, now one record-set (type A - ip4) is pointing to CloudFront, and another one is pointing to the S3 bucket (type A - ip4). Now I can see my index.html when i visit the website, but I can't visit the other pages because of 403-error and I also can't see SSL-certificate. The header-response still returns S3 as server.

Comment: You will always see `Server: Amazon S3` but you won't see `X-Cache` or `Via` unless the request is going through CloudFront.  You should only have 1 A record.

Comment: ok, so only one A-record pointing to the S3-bucket?

Comment: correction, I have only on A-record pointing to the Cloudfront-domain.

Comment: and my dns (in godaddy) is pointing to my S3-bucket.

Comment: so, you never found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

You will want to setup Origin Access Identity. This allows you to keep your bucket private and only allow access thru CloudFront. This is very easy to setup. I have included two links to walk you thru the steps and to help you understand everything.

[enter link description here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

[Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

This StackOverflow Q/A will help you also. Review the answer by "Michael - sqlbot".

[Relationship between Origin Access Identities and CloudFront Signed Urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929534/relationship-between-origin-access-identities-and-cloudfront-signed-urls)

Comment: thanks for your advice John. When I created the CloudFront-distribution, I selected "Origin Access Identity: Create a new Identity" and "Update Bucket Policy", isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Yes. Update your question with this information so that you get better answers.

Comment: The 403 means that you have a permissions issue. Did your S3 bucket already have a policy attached when you then added CloudFront OAI policy? CloudFront will add to your policy but will not delete the current policy. If this is the case, delete the S3 policy attached to your bucket and then have CloudFront recreate the OAI policy.

Comment: I just recreated the OAI policy while the S3-bucket had no other policy, still the same issue (403 when visiting the website)